# Unity: handle case when camera is restricted

Tags: android, android-camera, unity-game-engine, android-permissions

I'm using WebCamTexture to display Android camera output as background. The code looks like this:

```
image = GetComponent<RawImage> ();
cam = new WebCamTexture (Screen.width, Screen.height);
image.texture = cam;
```

It works, but when I remove permissions for Camera, it shows black screen. How can I handle this case and show my picture instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to check if you got permission (null-check it) and handle them differently.

See more [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/request-and-get-state-of-camera-permission.281858/)